# Android Webview(to render latex and html images) with Radiobutton

Tags: android, html, webview, mathjax, android-radiobutton

I am trying to develop a Maths Question and answer Native Android application where there are a dynamic number of answer options. And answers can contain Latex and image content. So I have to use Webview. Since User should be able to select only one option I have to wrap it in a radio group with dynamic number of radioButtons(because of dynamic answer options).

I have tried using Linearlayout to wrap the webview & Listview with webview, and other popular methods. But nothing works.

Is there any other way we can achieve this in Android? How can I achieve this?

Comment: post what you are tried

Comment: <ListView
                    android:id="@+id/fragment_question_lv"
                    android:layout_width="match_parent"
                    android:layout_height="1200dp"
                    android:layout_below="@id/fragment_question_wv"
                    android:layout_marginTop="@dimen/margin_4dp"
 >As you can see android:height has to be fixed to actually show the contents. There is another xml with just webview in it. since it is webview onclick on listitem doesnt work. This is one method@CoDfather

Comment: And <LinearLayout {{with neccesary attributes}}><WebView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:id="@+id/row_wv"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

</WebView></LinearLayout>. Inflating this in loop and tried to set on click on linearlayout and on touch on webview. Neither works cos it allows multiple selection. since inflating in loop, i am not able to change selection of previously selected views @CoDfather